# Firebird group clause

Tags: sql, firebird

I can't to understand firebird group logic

Query:

```
SELECT t.id FROM T1 t 
INNER JOIN T2 j  ON j.id = t.jid 
WHERE t.id = 1
GROUP BY t.id
```

works perfectly

But when I try to get other fields:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 t 
INNER JOIN T2 j  ON j.id = t.jid 
WHERE t.id = 1
GROUP BY t.id
```

I get error: `Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY in firebird](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171901/how-to-use-group-by-in-firebird)

Comment: This behavior is behavior defined in the SQL standard, only MySQL allows you to not specify all columns in the group by (with undefined behavior for the columns you don't specify).

Comment: should I remove the question, because it is duplicate?

Comment: You could delete it, but it will probably get closed as duplicate in the next few days. And although it is a duplicate, both your question and the answers are OK, so they might still be helpful to someone, even if it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `GROUP BY` in your query, the field or fields specified are used as 'keys', and data rows are grouped based on unique combinations of those 2 fields. In the result set, every such unique combination has one and only one row.

In your case, the only identifier in the group is `t.id`. Now consider that you have 2 records in the table, both with `t.id = 1`, but having different values for another column, say, `t.name`. If you try to select both `id` and `name` columns, it directly contradicts the constraint that one group can have only one row. That is why you cannot select any field apart from the group key.

For aggregate functions it is different. That is because, when you sum or count values or get the maximum, you are basically performing that operation only based on the `id` field, effectively ignoring the data in the other columns. So, there is no issue because there can only be one answer to, say, count of all names with a particular id.

In conclusion, if you want to show a column in the results, you need to group by it. This will however, make the grouping more granular, which may not be desirable. In that case, you can do something like this:

```
select * from T1 t
where t.id in
(SELECT t.id FROM T1 t 
 INNER JOIN T2 j  ON j.id = t.jid 
 WHERE t.id = 1
 GROUP BY t.id)
```

Comment: but I want to group by primary key and select only `t.*`, so `you have 2 records in the table` is impossible in my case... In any case, all is clear, thanks

Comment: Perhaps I should add that only the group key is 'exposed' to the select, but I am not really sure that's the best or even the right way of expressing it.

Answer (score 1):

When you using `GROUP BY` clause in `SELECT` you should use only aggreagted functions or columns that listed in `GROUP BY` clause. More about `GROUP BY` clause:http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/nullguide-aggrfunc.html

As example:

```
SELECT Max(t.jid), t.id FROM T1 t 
INNER JOIN T2 j  ON j.id = t.jid 
WHERE t.id = 1
GROUP BY t.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM T1 t 
INNER JOIN T2 j  ON j.id = t.jid 
WHERE t.id = 1
GROUP BY t.id
```

This will not execute,cause you have used t.id in group by, So all your columns in select clause should be using aggregate function , else those should be included in group by clause.
Select * means you are selecting all columns, so all columns except t.id are neither in group by nor in aggregate function.

Try this link, [How to use GROUP BY in firebird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171901/how-to-use-group-by-in-firebird)